# How to make active item bases on two arrays in angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, oop

I have two arrays

Initial array -   $scope.mentors = ["000", "001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", "009", "010", "011", "012", "013", "014"];

And matched  items of first array -   $scope.initialSelected = ["005", "009",  "013", "014"];

I need to render all $scope.mentors and highlight items from second array using class currentAcc. 
Also I need toggle items by clicking and create new array based on highliting elements.

Right now I have a bug trying to click initialized highlited elements.. Can anyone help me please with this?

Here is example of my app

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="mentor in mentors">
       <span ng-click="toggle = !toggle;" ng-class="{'currentAcc': ifActiveAcc(toggle, '{{mentor}}' )}">{{mentor}}
       </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.mentors = ["000", "001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", "009", "010", "011", "012", "013", "014"];

  $scope.initialSelected = ["005", "009",  "013", "014"];

  $scope.ifActiveAcc = function(flag, num){
      var p = $scope.initialSelected.includes(num);
      if(flag == undefined) {
         if (p){
           return true;
         }
       }
       else if(flag !== 'undefined'){
        if (flag && p){
          return true;
        }
        else if(flag && !p){
          return true;
        }
        else if(!flag && p){
          return false;
        }
        else{
          return false;
        }
       }             
  } 
}
```

agnular 1.6.9

Comment: here is example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abjxpcn7/3/

Comment: well, `toggle` is initially undefined, and even though your function returns the state of the flag, it doesn't actually change it.  therefore your `ng-click` doesn't really toggle from the correct state for the items that are initially highlighted.  To reliably solve this, you really should have mentors be an array of objects, holding the value and the state of each object, which eliminates the need for your function entirely.

Comment: thank your for tip, almost done with some pain.. Can you have a look at here http://jsfiddle.net/abjxpcn7/5/ please? How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

With the addition of the extra `isActive` field, there is no need for functions at all.  You can use simple direct evaluations.

```
<span ng-click="mentor.isActive = !mentor.isActive" 
      ng-class="{'currentAcc': mentor.isActive}">{{mentor.name}}
```

see this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/c84tf7Lu/